# Why am I getting MySQL error 1822 when creating a new table with a FOREIGN KEY?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I tried

```
CREATE TABLE `valorant`.`abilities` (
`PlayerId` INT NOT NULL,
`AgentName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`AbilityName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`KeyBind` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Cost` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`PlayerId`, `AgentName`, `AbilityName`));

CREATE TABLE `valorant`.`abilitystats` (
`PlayerId` INT NOT NULL,
`AgentName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`AbilityName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`EnemiesAffected` INT NULL,
`AlliesAffected` INT NULL,

CONSTRAINT `FK_abilitystats_abilities`
FOREIGN KEY (`AbilityName`, `AgentName`)
REFERENCES `abilities` ( `AgentName`, `AbilityName`),
PRIMARY KEY (`PlayerId`)
);
```

This is the error i got

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'FK_abilitystats_abilities' in the referenced table 'abilities'

I have no idea what is wrong with this. i follow a tutorial for `FOREIGN KEY`

Comment: i tried add all PK from abilities table to FK in abilitystats and it works, but i don't really know why
```
    FOREIGN KEY (`PlayerId`,`AbilityName`, `AgentName`)
    REFERENCES `abilities` ( `PlayerId`,`AgentName`, `AbilityName`),
```

Comment: Add additional information to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Your schema is very confusing. In `abilitystats` you can't have duplicate `PlayerId`, but you can have duplicates in `abilities`.

Comment: Clearly when pinned down this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an index that matches the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE abilities ADD INDEX (`AgentName`, `AbilityName`);
```

Note that usually it's better for a foreign key to reference the primary key of the other table.

Comment: I have them as PK in the abilities table. PRIMARY KEY (`PlayerId`, `AgentName`, `AbilityName`));. that's why I'm confused. it is supposed to work fine.....

Comment: The primary key begins with `PlayerId`, so `AgentName, AbilityName` isn't a key by itself.

Comment: Only the prefix of a key is a key by itself.

Comment: Thank you sir! it works for me. can you recommend me where should I read about that. Im new to database and how do I upvote this as well

Comment: See the [documentation of multi-column indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Answer (score 3):

Like @Barmar said The primary key begins with PlayerId, so AgentName, AbilityName isn't a key by itself. All i did was to move `PlayerId` to end in PRIMARY KEY ( `AgentName`, `AbilityName`,`PlayerId`));